# Alfresco 5.1 CE: Deactivating __CheckInOut.exe and __ShowDetails.exe

Tags: alfresco

we intend to upgrade vom Alfresco 4.2f to Alfresco 5.1 CE and are currently testing, whether required features are available in the new version, too.

One stop point is the chance to deactivate the two files __CheckInOut.exe and __ShowDetails.exe which are created in every directory. 
We managed to do this in 4.2f and according to the documentation of 5.1, all we have to do is to copy the directory of the subsystem "fileServers" to the directory of the new version.
We did this an had to deactivate e.g. some NFS instructions (which prooves that Alfresco is reading this directory). But although the required line are set as a comment in subsystems/fileServers/default/file-servers-context.xml:

```
<!--
                 <bean class="org.alfresco.filesys.repo.desk.CheckInOutDesktopAction">
                    <property name="name">
                       <value>CheckInOut</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="filename">
                       <value>__CheckInOut.exe</value>
                    </property>
                 </bean>
                 <bean class="org.alfresco.filesys.repo.desk.JavaScriptDesktopAction">
                    <property name="name">
                       <value>JavaScriptURL</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="filename">
                       <value>__ShowDetails.exe</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="scriptName">
                       <value>alfresco/desktop/showDetails.js</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="attributeList">
                       <value>anyFiles</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="preprocess">
                       <value>copyToTarget</value>
                    </property>
                 </bean>
            -->
```

still every directory contains the two files.
Does anyone know how they are hidden/deactivated in the new version?

Thanks for any help or hint,

Stefan

Answer (score 1):

I was able to answer the question myself:

With Alfresco 5.1 the files *file-servers-context.xml* and *file-servers.properties* have to be saved in the directory */opt/alfresco-community/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/subsystems/fileServers/default/default*, then the two exe files will disappear.

Regards,

Stefan